# MVC5 with ReportViewerForMvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I am designing an MVC application using ReportViewerForMVC. This is my controller code:

```
ReportViewer rp = new ReportViewer();
rp.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rp.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath)
                + @"Report/sampleFile.rdlc";
ViewBag.ReportViewer = rp;
```

This is my View:

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewerMicrosoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

The iframe shows but i get this message:

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.

as my output for the report section. I thought i specified my data source when designing my .rdlc file. 
Again, i want to ask if i create a datatable with a where clause having parameter, how can i specify the value in my controller.

I have searched online and i'm not getting any useful. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The report viewer has no DataSource. If you like using designer view like myself, you could start by creating a dataset and adding a dataAdapter which will automatically add a dataTable. The dataSource can be set like this:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
TableAdapter1 ta = new TableAdapter1();
ta.Fill(ds.Table[0]);

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet";
rds.Value = ds.Table[0];
rp.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
rp.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
rp.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

As simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in View

```
@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewerMicrosoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

to

```
@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```